# ¿Por qué la función printf no funciona cuando se programa con ventanas en Windows y en Linux si?¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Tags: c, windows, c++11, printf

He hecho algunos programas en Linux con ventanas usando estas librerias, (XLib,  QT3, wxWidgets) y siempre me ha funcionado la función printf. También he hecho algunos programas en Windows, con (QT3, wxWidgets, vcl de Borland, incluso el API de Windows a pelo) y nunca me ha funcionado la función printf. Si no recuerdo mal con la única libreria que me ha funcionado printf en Windows ha sido con Allegro o SDL (una de las dos). Me gustaría saber cúal es el motivo de esto y si es posible hacer que esta función funcione de alguna forma porque sustituir la función printf() por MessageBox() o similar que es lo que he hecho siempre la verdad es que me parece muy poco práctico y también bastante incomodo.

Lo mismo ocurre cuando se usa el **cout** de C++... El problema es el mismo en ambos lenguajes tanto en C como en C++. Lo que yo creo es que han deshabilitado la salida estandar y lo que yo quiero saber es como volver a habilitarla... que de hecho sé que se puede porque como dije antes con la libreria de Allegro o la SDL ese problema no existe y sin embargo se usan ventanas.

Comment: ¿La duda es sobre [tag:c] o sobre [tag:c++]?

Comment: Es indiferente, el problema se da en los dos casos y supongo que en los dos casos tenga la misma solución

Comment: No es indiferente. Son lenguajes distintos y aunque el problema surja con ambos la solución puede variar en cada caso.

Comment: Ok, puede que tengas razón. En ese caso estoy interesado en saber ambas soluciones.

Comment: No estoy entendiendo la pregunta, tampoco después de tu edición. ¿A qué te refieres con que no funciona `printf` ni `cout`? ¿surge un fallo en tiempo de ejecución/compilación? ¿el programa reacciona de una manera inesperada? ¿esperas ver algo por pantalla y no lo ves?

Comment: SI, exacto, espero ver algo por pantalla y no lo veo... simplemente no sale nada, es como si printf o cout no tuvieran ningún efecto

Comment: Es normal que ni `printf` ni `cout` tengan efecto alguno en un entorno de ventanas porque son utilidades de comunicación con la salida estándar. La salida estándar es la consola no una ventana. En sistemas Unix ves la salida estándar porque invocas la aplicación desde consola, en sistemas Windows puedes ver la salida estándar si tu programa de ventanas [crea una ventana de consola](http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm).

Comment: Muchas gracias Paula!! Le doy un vistazo a ese artículo

Comment: No te lo vas a creer... he compilado el ejemplo que me has dado sin errores y se ejecuta sin excepciones... pero por algún motivo no redirecciona la salida a la consola. Es decir que estamos en las mismas... Voy a ver si encuentro otro ejemplo por ahi que funcione. Pero gracias de todas formas por lo menos ahora sé cual es el problema. Saludos!!

Comment: Solucionado!! :-) Solo hay que añadir este flag (-mconsole) a los parametros de compilación y no es necesario implementar ninguna función para redireccionar la salida a la consola!! Estupendo!! :-)

Comment: @IvánRodríguez me alegro de que hayas encontrado una solución al problema. Por favor, ponlo como respuesta y márcala como aceptada cuando pase el tiempo requerido. De ese modo, si algún otro usuario tiene la misma duda podrá encontrar la repuesta fácilmente aquí. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Ok, lo haré. Un Saludo Alvaro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado una solución al problema. Para habilitar la salida estandar cuando se programa en un entorno de ventanas en Windows. Simplemente hay que añadir este flag (-mconsole) a los parametros del compilador. Quedando algo así:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp  -o test.exe -IC:/../Include -D_WIN32 -DVK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR -LC:/.../Lib -mwindows -mconsole
```

Esta solución sirve para el compilador gcc y g++, desconozco si funcionará con otro compilador, aunque es muy probable que si ese compilador no tiene exactamente la misma opción tenga una que sea análoga a esta.